# Подсчёт лет на основании количества указанных

Tags: php, modx

Странная задача и всё же.
CMS Modx Revo, но мне и обычный php вариант будет полезен.
Есть два TV (текстовых поля): tv_name_1 и tv_name_2

В первом указывается целое число или с одном знаком после запятой (1; 1,5, 2; 2,5 и т.д.), т.е. с шагом в 0,5. Каждая единица = 1 году (365 дней).

При сохранении необходимо вызывать данный сниппет (запускать скрипт, не важно), чтобы он брал значение из tv_name_1 и производил вычисления: текущая дата «-»(минус) введенная в поле = результат заносится в БД в tv_name_2.

Главное, что меня интересует: как произвести вычисление на php?

Comment: Вот так вычесть некоторое кол-Во дней. 
Strtotime('-180 days'); Остальное пробуйте писать, подскажем

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate($ratio) {
    $now = new DateTime();
    $hours = $ratio * 365 * 24;
    return $now->modify("-{$hours} hours")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

$tv_name_2 = calculate($tv_name_1);
```